# What is the concurrence between A and BC?

Tags: concurrence

I was studing about the monogamy.
Then I saw this phrase

$$C_{AB}^2 + C_{AC}^2 ≤ C_{A(BC)}^2$$
where  $C_{AB}, C_{AC} $ are the concurrences between A and B and between A and C respectively, while  $C_{A(BC)}$ is the concurrence between subsystems A and BC.

I know what the the concurrence of a bipartite system is,
I just dont know how to calculate   $C_{A(BC)}$, that is the concurrence between subsystems A and BC. How I do this?

Comment: $A(BC)$ is a bipartite system. Do you mean you don't know how to calculate it when one of the subsystem has dimension > 2? If so [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0102040) might help. Or see the definition of the "tangle" in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0502176).

Comment: U mean I should consider A as a partite and the qubits B and C both together as other partite?